# Showing class view for android SDK source code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

From Android Studio, we can see Android SDK classes like "Activitiy.java", "Toast.java" by pressing ctrl+alt+B from my own source code. How can I see the class view of these class when they are selected?

For source that I wrote, I can see the class view on the left pane by choosing "Show Members". But, how can I make Android Studio to do the same for Android SDK classes?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this almost the same night. Not the the best, but it gave me the class view I wanted.

Locate the sdk source which installed as part of Android Studio download: ....\Android\sdk\sources\android-22. You path could be different. Please launch SDK manager, it will show you the sdk path.

Fire up "Eclipse", create a new Java project. Import the file structure from above path. Now you have the nice package view on the left, and Class view on the right under "Outline".

I wish I could do the same with Android Studio.